# Issue while setting Footer layout in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, footer

Below is my Footer Layout for setting it for my ListView :

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray_cell_bg">

    <TextView
        android:text="footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It's working fine. But, What if I want to set an emptyview with some background color in my ListView's footer ?

If I am doing it as below, ListView not showing footer view. :

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray_cell_bg">

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am setting footer as below :

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_for_gym_list, null);
        listGymSuggestions.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Please guide me How can I set empty footer with some height and background color in ListView ?

Comment: you can heck with `View`    in place of `RelativeLayout` ,  with height of view it should be work let me know if not work.

Comment: You have to provide height attribute . Without any child your Layout as footer will not show .

Comment: You know what @PragatiSingh I gave the same answer5 but someone keep downvoting without even saying. Where did I do wrong??

Comment: Now they have removed their downvotes!

Comment: Apart from this, I have taken a SearchView. and onCLose() method is not calling.. Or please. guide How can I fired close event when pressing on X(close) icon of Android SearchView ?  NOTE : I know it will be better if i ask new question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `View` is there but it has NO `height` so you must add your own height value may be `24dp` or something and set it as a footer you can even add a `width` if you want. For instance here I am adding a height of `24dp`**:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="@color/gray_cell_bg">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no child in that layout, It will not be shown. If you have problem with setting specific height(when you are adding child dynamically), you can use **padding** like,

```
android:padding="20dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a button as a footer in one of my layout.
Here is my code. You may add anything you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
    layout="@layout/search_toolbar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/indeterminateBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/emp_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_toolbar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvsample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/search_toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:id="@+id/emp_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/Red"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_employee"
    android:text="@string/emp_button"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved by adding an ImageView in Footer view as below :

**footer.xml** :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray_cell_bg">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/com_facebook_profilepictureview_preset_size_normal"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@color/gray_cell_bg" />
</RelativeLayout>
```